# pyspark query on case statement throws error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the below pyspark query

It throws the below error .  I want dynamic values to passes via a varaibale in to case statement

```
 data1 = 'HI'
 data2 = 'HELLO'

 spark.sql(f""" select  Initials,
                case when Initials  in ('AM','NJ') then {data1} else {data2} end as s  
                from omegawriter""").display()
```

I get below error

```
  A column or function parameter with name `HI` cannot be resolved.
  Project [Initials#69, CASE WHEN Initials#69 IN (AM,NJ) THEN 'HI ELSE 'HELLO END AS s#57]
```

I dont understand what is the problem with this query . Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain text values need to be quoted.

```
 spark.sql(f""" select  Initials,
                case when Initials  in ('AM','NJ') then '{data1}' else '{data2}' end as s  
                from omegawriter""").display()
```

Comment: This answer saved lot of of my development  time. very useful